# Cant open phpMyAdmin

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, php, mysql

Error Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

I'm using widows 7.

I am saving session values in database, after saving session id, i have cleaned the database once, from that i cant open phpmyadmin

I gave permission to /tmp (listed as sessions path in php.ini).

Tried multiple web browsers, deleting cookies, deleting all session files from server's /tmp folder.

still the error exists

Do i need to uninstall Xampp ?? will it be okay if i reinstall xampp??

Comment: Did you check for errors, as the message says?

Answer (score 1):

Normaly it should work out of the box. Apache and MySQL have to be started.
You can try to use the portable xampp version: [Portable Version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.2.7/)

Hint: To use the portable version the installed apache server and mysql server has to be stopped in advance.